# Error when trying to add a button

Tags: android, button

When I try to run it in my AVD, it gives me an error that says: 
Sorry! the application Hello World (process com.duncan.hello.world) has stopped unexpectedly. Please try again. 
I think it has something to do with adding in the code for the second button, because it worked fine before that. This is the code that i have in my main java file:

```
package com.duncan.hello.world;  

import android.app.Activity; 
import android.content.Intent; 
import android.os.Bundle; 
import android.view.View; 
import android.view.View.OnClickListener; 
import android.widget.Button;  
import com.duncan.hello.world.R;  

public class HelloWorldActivity extends Activity { 
/** Called when the activity is first created. */ 
@Override 
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {     
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);     
    setContentView(R.layout.main);     

              Button aButton;
    aButton = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.button1);

    aButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {         
        public void onClick(View v) {             

Intent i = new Intent (HelloWorldActivity.this, OtherActivity.class);             
            startActivity(i);       
            }
        }); 

    Button newButton;

    newButton = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.meh);

    newButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {         
        public void onClick(View v) {             
Intent i = new Intent(HelloWorldActivity.this, Meh.class);             
            startActivity(i);       
            }
        });

    } 
}
```

this is the other.xml(the layout where meh is):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="you...are...on...page...2...!!!" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/meh"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="meh"/>


<Button
    android:id="@+id/p40"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="this go to p40" />

</LinearLayout>
```

here is the Meh.java:

```
package com.duncan.hello.world;
import com.duncan.hello.world.R;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
public class Meh extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.meh);
}
}
```

logcat errors:
12-07 14:40:00.840: E/AndroidRuntime(497): FATAL EXCEPTION: main

12-07 14:40:00.840: E/AndroidRuntime(497): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.duncan.hello.world/com.duncan.hello.world.HelloWorldActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException

12-07 14:40:00.840: E/AndroidRuntime(497):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)

12-07 14:40:00.840: E/AndroidRuntime(497):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)

12-07 14:40:00.840: E/AndroidRuntime(497):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)

12-07 14:40:00.840: E/AndroidRuntime(497):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)

12-07 14:40:00.840: E/AndroidRuntime(497):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)

12-07 14:40:00.840: E/AndroidRuntime(497):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)

12-07 14:40:00.840: E/AndroidRuntime(497):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main
(ActivityThread.java:4627)

12-07 14:40:00.840: E/AndroidRuntime(497):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)

12-07 14:40:00.840: E/AndroidRuntime(497):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)

12-07 14:40:00.840: E/AndroidRuntime(497):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)

12-07 14:40:00.840: E/AndroidRuntime(497):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)

12-07 14:40:00.840: E/AndroidRuntime(497):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

12-07 14:40:00.840: E/AndroidRuntime(497): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException

12-07 14:40:00.840: E/AndroidRuntime(497):  at com.duncan.hello.world.HelloWorldActivity.onCreate(HelloWorldActivity.java:32)

12-07 14:40:00.840: E/AndroidRuntime(497):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)

12-07 14:40:00.840: E/AndroidRuntime(497):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)

12-07 14:40:00.840: E/AndroidRuntime(497):  ... 11 more

Comment: Use the `adb logcat` command to get stack trace & other detailed info about your error.

Comment: What does it say in LogCat?

1. Make sure the meh button is there and it's really a button, not an imagebutton.
2. Make sure you the Meh activity is added in the Android.manifest file

Comment: i have the Meh.java file in my package, and i have the Meh.activity in the manifest.

Comment: You can just copy and paste the LogCat errors from Eclipse. Copy those and report back, Then we'll be able to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you give your logcat output? If the problems occurred after you added the second button, then is it because Meh.java is not in your mainfest file?

Logcat output can be found if you switch views (top right hand corner) to DDMS, and then click LogCat. Click the W or the E in the right hand side of the logcat window, it should show you the warnings and errors that occurred. Your crash will be red, so copy paste that part to show us the problem.

Your problem is that you are declaring

```
Button aButton;
```

before you call the super onCreate  method. You have to call super.onCreate(bundleInstanceState) before you do anything else.

What you want to do is more like:

```
public class HelloWorldActivity extends Activity { 
    Button aButton;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        //whatever button listeners you want to create and initialize buttons
     }
 }
```

You mentioned that the 'meh' button is in other.xml. It is supposed to be in main.xml. Add a button with the id 'meh' in main.xml.

Comment: Add the whole path to the name, and please show your logcat error message as well.

Comment: okay, the tutorial i was using told me to declare the button before the onCreate(). no, it didn't work. same error.

Comment: Can you paste your main.xml? Does the id 'meh' exist for  a Button in main.xml?

Comment: okay..... ill try that, but my problam isn't with the button, it's when i try to add multiple buttons.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your content view is main.xml - not other.xml. If your 'meh' button is not in main.xml, you will get a NullPointerException.